# Rails + Nginx + Unicorn - The webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I have a rails project that I just deployed to my AWS server. But when I access the IP address of the instance it returns:

**The webpage has a redirect loop**

This is my nginx conf file

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf

upstream unicorn {
server unix:/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 12.34.56.78;
    root /home/ubuntu/var/www/myapp/current/public;
    return 301 http://12.34.56.78$request_uri;
    access_log on;
}

server {
    listen 443 default;
    server_name 12.34.56.78;
    root /home/ubuntu/var/www/myapp/current/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

    location @unicorn {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off; proxy_pass http://unicorn;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I am using nginx + unicorn.

Can anybody shed some light into what I might be doing wrong here. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `return 301 http://12.34.56.78$request_uri;` should probably be redirecting to `https`.

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith my website does not have `https` yet. Thank you for your reply.